# How to add element to list if it's not there with 'lens'?

Tags: list, haskell, haskell-lens

Let's say I have a list `[A]`. I want to update specific element of list if it satisfies some predicate. But if there's no such element I want to add element to list first. My current solution is to write manually function for inserting element into list if it's not there and then use `filtered` Traversal to update my element. Like this:

```
-- inserts element to list if there's no a single element 
-- which satisfies given predicate 
insertIfNot :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> [a] -> [a]
insertIfNot _ e []       = [e]
insertIfNot p e l@(x:xs) = if p x then l else x : insertIfNot p e xs

functionIWantToWrite :: [A] -> [A]
functionIWantToWrite = modifyItem . addEmptyItem
  where
    addEmptyItem = insertIfNot myPredicate item
    modifyItem   = each.filtered myPredicate %~ myUpdate
```

I wonder if there's better (shorter, more idiomatic) solution? If possible I would appreciate solution which uses only [`microlens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens) family of packages.

Comment: @chepner very close but not exactly. As you can see, I'm using lists, so efficiency is not top priority for me. Though I think my solution is already efficient enough and probably even uses only one traversal of list. I want shorter form (w/o big loss of efficiency). And I'm interested in solution which uses lenses (because w/o lenses I can do it myself). The difference is that in your form `myUpdate` should check whether to modify element while in my form `map myUpdate` will change every element of the list. But your idea is very close to what I want.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I figured out what you really wanted, then forgot to delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `has` to shorten it a little:

```hs
functionIWantToWrite :: [A] -> [A]
functionIWantToWrite = modifyItem . addEmptyItem
  where
    _items = filtered myPredicate
    addEmptyItem list | has _items list = list
                      | otherwise       = item : list 
    modifyItem = each . _items %~ myUpdate
```

If you really wanted to shorten it, you might be able to just get it as a single traversal using the `Monoid m => Applicative (m,)` instance or so, something like

```hs
accAny :: (x -> Bool) -> (x -> x) -> x -> (Any, x)
accAny pred fn x = (Any b, if b then fn x else x)
  where b = pred x

functionIWantToWrite list = handle . traverse . accAny myPredicate myUpdate $ list
  where handle (Any True, list) = list
        handle (_, list) = item : list
```